# Java string encoding(getBytes not working)

Tags: java, servlets, utf-8, big5

Now I have a return message in Chinese from API, it used **big5** to encode.
Unfortunately, my web page used **UTF-8**, so it cant't show properly.

I google this question many times, so I **tried different getBytes function many times**, and I don't want to use file system to handle it as far as possible.  So can anyone supply an effective solution to me?

My JDK version is 1.7, and sorry that this version can't change in this project.

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the encoding/decoding methods present in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html